# Promote element with usort()

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a simple array that looks like this:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'primary' => boolean false
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 2
      'primary' => boolean false
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 3
      'primary' => boolean false
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 4
      'primary' => boolean true
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 5
      'primary' => boolean false
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 6
      'primary' => boolean false
```

When the array is generated, it is always ordered by `id`, like the above. What I wish to do is to have `usort()` promote the array element where `primary` is `TRUE` to be the first element. There will always only be one element where `primary` is `TRUE`.

I then wrote a simple comparison function to use with `usort()`:

```
$data = array(
            array('id' => 1, 'primary' => FALSE),
            array('id' => 2, 'primary' => FALSE),
            array('id' => 3, 'primary' => FALSE),
            array('id' => 4, 'primary' => TRUE),
            array('id' => 5, 'primary' => FALSE),
            array('id' => 6, 'primary' => FALSE),
        );

function sortArray($a, $b){

    if($a['primary']){
        return -1;
    }elseif($b['primary']){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

var_dump($data);

usort($data, 'sortArray');

var_dump($data);
```

While the element with `primary = TRUE` is now promoted to the front, the rest of the elements are now sorted in reverse order and the element with `id = 5` is out of place:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 4
      'primary' => boolean true
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 5
      'primary' => boolean false
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 6
      'primary' => boolean false
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 3
      'primary' => boolean false
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 2
      'primary' => boolean false
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'primary' => boolean false
```

I know I can compare the ids, if both elements have the `primary` property as false:

```
function sortArray($a, $b){

    if($a['primary']){
        return -1;
    }elseif($b['primary']){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return $a['id'] > $b['id'];
    }
}
```

But, why is `usort` randomizing the order of my other elements? Is it possible to use `usort()` to just promote elements and leave the rest of the array untouched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this comparison function:

```
function sortArray($a, $b)
{
    if($a['primary'])
    {
        $result = 1;
    }
    elseif($b['primary'])
    {
        $result = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        $result = ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

You can change `$result = ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;` to `$result = ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? 1 : -1;` to sort in reverse order.

In your comparison function, `return $a['id'] > $b['id']` will either return 0 or 1 (true or false), never -1. From the documentation:

"The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

The fastest comparison sort is O(N*log(N)), which is slower than linear time. For this reason, I recommend just iterating over the array (O(N), linear time) and moving the element with 'primary' set to `true` to the front of the array.

Answer (score 0):

[usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) will reindex keys. Try using [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) instead.